# S3 HTTPS object URL not accessible via vpc endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, wget, amazon-vpc

I configured S3 Gateway VPC endpoint in my account and created a S3 bucket (Bucket-A) with no public access. I configured the below Bucket Policy in Bucket-A and tried to access a png file in that bucket using CURL and WGET from an EC2 instance and ended up with "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" error. But call via AWS CLI works fine which proves that traffic via VPCEndpoint works fine. eg: aws s3 ls s3://Bucket-A.
Can you people help me to understand what configuration should be done additionally to make the CURL and WGET GET operation work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket-A/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-xyzxyzxyz"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

VPC Endpoint Policy:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does `aws s3 cp` work from the EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes it works well when I use the AWS CLI but not with CURL or WGET.

Comment: The AWS CLI is able to use the instance profile to perform authorized requests to AWS.

Comment: Yes , thats my understanding too. How can we make a curl or wget call which can access a S3 object through VPC Endpoints? any idea?